Automated way to compare similar text columns in Excel?
I am happy to join you here.
I have an excel sheet that contains thousands of rows, and there is two columns that contains similar text, sometimes identical, and sometimes long.
What I need is a way to get the differences of every row of these two columns, maybe in two cells for example: one for the additions from the first column, and the other for the additions from the second one.
It's OK/better if there is a way to highlight the differences instead of these one/two columns of differences.
Notes:

the differences I am interested in are text addition/deletion, text colors, underlines, bold/normal (the first is essential, the rest are nice if possible).

I would be great if there is a way to specify a character or more to be ignored.

I had found two useful links (I think) but I don't know how to use them (I tried!):
1- https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/vba-routine-to-perform-text-diff.714927/page-2
2- https://mectile.com/2010/04/23/longest-common-subsequence-implemented-in-vba-visual-basic-for-applications/


Thank you

Hi and welcome, could we have a screenshot of the excel or at least a skeleton of it

Hello, Lets make it simple. A1 contain long text, B1 contain similar text with some differences, and C1 is the place I want to see the differences in. and so on for the next rows.
